# RegEx to Parse SharePoint Multi-Value XML Result

Tags: regex, sharepoint

Good day, fellow **SO'ers**,

I'm using **[my favorite RegEx Tool](http://www.regexr.com/)** to parse the string:

```
5;#.NET;#26;#ASP.NET;#1;#SharePoint;#3;#Windows Server;#20;#DB2
```

I'm using PowerShell to query SharePoint Web Services via CAML where I'm parsing the returned XML into a meaningful PSObject to run some business logic.

I was going to `.split()` on `;#` but I did not like the result.  *Note: I may reconsider this later but I would like the answer to be more so about the proper RegEx for this...*

The string result will be consistent, in this format every time, starting with a number and ending with no semi-colon `;`.

I want to extract the ID and Value.  If it's not obvious, the ID being the integer and the Value being the string between the `#` and the `;`.

My RegEx reflexes aren't quite batman-level yet, and this particular string is a challenge for me.  I want to produce a clean result consisting of an ID and Value as the capture groups...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wQ5qQ5)**

I think this expression should work:  `/(\d+)(?:[;][#])([\w.]+)/g`

Comment: Haha, I edited my comment because you fixed it so quickly.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I learned from you today.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

The non-regex way if you have access to Microsoft.SharePoint.dll assembly is to use [SPFieldLookupValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookupvaluecollection_members.aspx):

```
new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValueCollection "5;#.NET;#26;#ASP.NET;#1;#SharePoint;#3;#Windows Server;#20;#DB2"

                                       LookupId LookupValue                                   
                                       -------- -----------                                   
                                              5 .NET                                          
                                             26 ASP.NET                                       
                                              1 SharePoint                                    
                                              3 Windows Server                                
                                             20 DB2
```

Comment: +1. I appreciate this solution very much because it is in PS and I do have access to that DLL.  Thanks much for sharing.  I learned something from you today.

Answer (score 1):

When wanting to remove only the ';#' that comes after a string you just need this:

```
string.split(/;#(?=\d)/g);
```

This

```
var string = "14;#Strategies/Policies;#6;#HR Systems;#154;#Design to Manufacture";
```

becomes

```
["14;#Strategies/Policies", "6;#HR Systems", "154;#Design to Manufacture"]
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/wQ5qQ5/4)

(?=\d) is a positive lookahead. Matches a group after your main expression without including it in the result.

So the whole thing is find the ';#' that precedes a digit but do not include the digit.
;#(?=\d)

The reason I keep the index & semicolon & hashtag is because that is what I send back to SP if I want more about that list item.